# Securing RESTful API: Is it possible to disallow XHR requests from the JS Console?

Tags: security, rest, xmlhttprequest

My application (mostly client-side code written in backbone) interfaces with a Node.js server.  The sole purpose of my server is to provide API endpoints for my backbone application.

`GET` requests are pretty safe, attackers can't do much here. But I do have a few POST and PUT requests. One of the `PUT` requests is responsible for updating vote count for a particular user, e.g.

```
app.put('/api/vote`, function(req, res) {
  // POST form data from the client
  var winningPerson = req.body.winner; // userID
  var losingPerson = req.body.loser;   // userID
}
```

I have noticed that some people were just spamming `PUT` requests for one particular user via JS console or some kind of REST API console, bypassing the intention of the application enforced by the User Interface. If you were to use this application as it is intended, it would never allow you to vote for the same person multiple times in a row, let alone any arbitrary user from the database (assuming you know their user id).

But yes, yes I know: "*Don't trust the client*". **So how can I fix the above problem?** Will some kind of *IP address* checking help here to prevent voting multiple times within a span of 3-5 minutes? **What can I do to disallow access to my API from the console so that users cannot arbitrarily vote for anyone they wish**, but instead only vote by clicking on an image with a mouse, or at the very least vote from console just for those two people, not any arbitrary person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies within your server. It shouldn't allow the user to vote more than once within the specified timespan. This is a kind of business rule you can enforce via server only because it's under your control.
Any enforcing in the UI is good and profitable, but is not bullet-proof. You definitely have to check on the server to be sure. There is much [more to the server's business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic#Scope_of_business_logic) than

> The sole purpose of my server is to provide API endpoints for my backbone application.

Don't try to control something that is out of your control - the client side of your application. Some people vote more times because you (your API) ALLOW them to do so. As soon as your server replies "Try in 5 minutes, dude." they'll stop doing this or there will be no harm when doing this at least.

Comment: Thanks for a great advice! Regarding my business logic, having a global session object that keeps track of people inside an array that have already been voted for, good idea?

Comment: Where do you keep your users and their votes? A database seems the best to me. Then I'd store last vote time of the user there to decide. But a global (application) object could help too - not session because it can be cheated.